# Como poner el FAB en el BottomBar en jetpack compose con el estilo personalizado

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, jetpack-compose

Estoy tratando de seguir las pautas de un diseño que se me hadado, este esta basado en material 3, tengo ya parte del diseño implementado pero tengo un inconveniente con la parte de centrar el FAB y quede como en el diseño, la problemática es que al momento de buscar en el internet como poder hacerlo todos aseguran usar el `isFloatingActionButtonDocked` pero en material 3 esa propiedad no esta, he estado haciendo pruebas y se ha visto que con xml es posible hacerlo y dejarlo como el diseño, pero la app esta tan avanzada que hacer el cambio no es viable, a continuación dejo una imagen de lo que se quiere lograr y como lo estoy tratando de hacer en compose que hasta ahora ha sido lo mejor que he podido hacer.

Como pueden ver, la imagen 1 es el diseño que se quiere implementar, la imagen 2 es como hasta el momento he logrado llegar, alguien podría ayudarme en como poder lograr a realizar esto?

Imagen 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]